# My app update has been rejected multiple times even though we addressed the issue

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Our app update has been rejected even though we addressed the issue. In the email with the details of the rejection says that we have some vulnerabilities with our recent submission but it says that the version that have issue is the one on the production channel:
[image]
and we didn't submit that version because it's already public, my latest version is 2021031602 (3.3.0) and as you can see in the image above that version doesn't have any vulnerability and I want to upload it to a closed test channel not production. I post this question here because I'm unable to get a proper response from the Google Play Team.
This is the most recent chat that I had with them:
[image]

[image]

Then I get this email:
[image]

But I never got an answer from the policy team, we have been running with this issue since January and honestly I don't know what else can we do.

Anyone who has been in this same situation? I'll really appreciate your input.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue with the following steps, in case someone is struggling to find how to remove a non complaining bundle/apk.

1. Go to your Play Console.
2. Select the app.
3. Go to App bundle explorer.
4. Select the non-compliant APK/app bundle's App version at the top right dropdown menu, and make a note of which releases they are under.
5. Go to the track with the policy issue. It will be one of these 4 pages: Internal / Closed / Open testing or Production. (If the bundle with the issue is on the production track, you'll need to upload an update directly to that track until you get to the step 8).
6. Near the top right of the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage track first)

- If the release with the violating APK is in a draft state, discard the release.

7. Add the policy compliant version of app bundles or APKs.
8. Make sure the non-compliant version of app bundles or APKs is under the Not included section of this release. For further guidance, please see the "Not included (app bundles and APKs)" section in this [Play Console Help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348#zippy=%2Cnot-included-app-bundles-and-apks).
9. To save any changes you make to your release, select Save.

When you've finished preparing your release, select Review release.
If the non-compliant APK is released to multiple tracks, repeat steps 5-9 in each track.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to update only one channel. Updating production in the same review fixed it for me.